# how to delete all the lines after a certain line in shell?

Tags: shell

I have a file like below

```
first line
second line
third line
forth line
```

I want to delete the lines after the second line but retain the second line. I have tried
`sed -i '/second line/,$d' filename` but it will delete the second line. How to modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove from the match of `^second line` to end of file, you will want to force an exit with `q` after the match, e.g.

```
sed '/^second line/q' file
```

(you can add `-i` to edit in-place)

**Example Use/Output**

With your lines in `file:`

```
$ sed '/^second line/q' file
first line
second line
```

Comment: but I got another question. How can I delete the n lines after the certain line(also remain the line I searched)

Comment: Hmm, when you say `n` lines -- how many do you mean? This answer deletes all after the matched pattern. Do you want to match the pattern and then delete the next 2 lines or so?

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer using `ed` over the non standard `sed -i` for editing files:

```
printf '%s\n' '3,$d' w | ed -s filename
```

will delete everything from the third line to the end of the file and save the changes.

Or if you don't mean the literal third line of the file but the first after a matching regular expression:

```
printf '%s\n' '/second line/+1,$d' w | ed -s filename
```

Comment: actually, I'm writing a shell script in windows and the script is working for my job mates. So it's better to not install ed or other something. Can you give me a direct solution?

Comment: @byhuang1998 You're targeting windows but you're okay with sed? If you can install that you can install ed. You're better off using powershell though.

Answer (score 0):

Print the matching line and remove all subsequent lines until the end of the file:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print and last if /second line/; print;' in_file
```

Print the matching line and remove `N` (here, `N=2`) subsequent lines from the file:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'if ( /second line/ ) { <> and next for 1..2; } print;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: @byhuang1998 Re: *How can I delete the n lines after the certain line* - see updated answer.